# Tag cloud/weighted list

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

What is mean by tag cloud, by using it how to display the frequently entered text from database...

Thanks...

Comment: A question ends with a question mark, but what I really mean is you're very unclear. Please explain your problem properly ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Your " frequently entered text " has counter or something similar, You can get them by SQL with

```
ORDER BY `counter` DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

statement.